# Programmatically switch tabs in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an iphone application which has about 4 tabs. How do I force the program to start on the second tab?

Currently I have switched the first and second tab, but the aesthetics are horrid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change the [selectedViewController](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedViewController) property

Comment: You should be able to use selectedIndex too if the view controller is already setup.

Comment: Yes, for this particular one of the second index, but for things that fall under "More" you can not, you must use this property.