# Switching between tabs programmatically

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to change tabs programmatically?

Switch tabs so the user sees another tabs view.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370813/programatically-switch-tabs-in-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `selectedIndex` on the [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
UITabBarController *tabbarController  = ...

...

tabbarController.selectedIndex = 1; //Tabs indexed from 0, left to right
```